# Changing one element in 2D Array results into changing all of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to understand the 2D Arrays in Google Apps script and I have been stuck with this unexpected behavior, I want to change just one element within an I and J position but it results to changing many ones.

```
function tryMe(){
  const total = Array(2).fill(Array(5).fill(0));
  Logger.log('Initial array : ');
  Logger.log(total);
  total[0][3] = 50;
  Logger.log('Replacing element (0, 3) with 50 : ');
  Logger.log(total);
}
```

The result I get :
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately this was closed without a good explaination.  Since `Array(5).fill(0)` creates an array (an object) `Array.fill(2)` will use the same array (object) so each row of `total` references the same array.  See this article [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

Comment: Use this instead: `Array(2).fill().map(() => Array(5));`.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 You might wish to direct that comment to TheWizEd

Comment: @TheWizEd I think it would be better if you

could post this comment as an answer to this question. The closed status has been lifted on the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
const total = Array(2).fill(Array(5).fill(0));
```

`Array(5).fill(0)` creates an array of 5 elements filled with 0.

However Array(2).fill() will fill the array with a value, but if the value is an object it will fill each element of the array with the same object.  Since an array is an object `total` will consist of 2 elements each being the same array.  So `total[0]` is the same array as `total[1]` and when you change `total[0][3] = 50;` you are also changing `total[1][3]`

A slight correction to my solution of yesterday.  Since Array.map() skips empty element you need to fill the array as shown below.

A solution would be:

```
let total = new Array(2).fill(0);
total = total.map( row => new Array(5).fill(0) );
```

Reference

- [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: In the case of your bottom script, how about modifying `const` to `let` or `var`? I'm worried that in your current script, an error like `Assignment to constant variable.` might occur.

Comment: Yes you are right. I simply copied the OP code. I rarely (never) use const.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, This syntax `Array(2).fill(<object>)` is a culprit. As per the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), If value of `fill()` is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.
Which means updating one object will modify all the object as all are referencing the same address.

To get rid from this, You can use Array.push() instead of Array.fill() for `<object>` values.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const total = [];

const parentArrayElements = 2;

for (let i = 1; i <= parentArrayElements; i++) {
  total.push(Array(5).fill(0))
}

console.log('Initial array : ');
console.log(total); // [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
total[0][3] = 50;
console.log('Replacing element (0, 3) with 50 : ');
console.log(total); // [[0, 0, 0, 50, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```